# How to delete specific document in the collection and with the auto generated id of firebase firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding a feature in my app i.e. favourite the specific item and save it to firestore. Adding the document is done but when i want to unfavourite the item and delete it from firestore. Than my code will delete all the item in it.So how can I delete specific document.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc('usr1').collection('favourite').snapshots().forEach((querySnapshot) {
   for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
      // docSnapshot.id;

       print("id of document========${docSnapshot.id}");
       var ids = docSnapshot.id;
     //deleting the doc with id

       db.collection("user").doc("usr1").collection("favourite").doc(ids).delete();
     
   }

  });
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No, actually i want to add the item into the array and then delete it. when i add the item it create the new document rather than add the next item value the array and delete the item is also work with this code 
`db.collection("user").where("id", 
isEqualTo : widget.saloonobj.id).get().then((value){
        value.docs.forEach((element) {
          db.collection("user").doc(element.id).delete().then((value){
            print("Success!");
           
          });
        });
      });`

Comment: This is not what your title says.

Comment: No, i delete specific with using `where` in the query and in the document i have assign the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `FieldValue.delete()`, like this:

```
 db.collection("user").doc("usr1").collection("favourite").doc(ids).update({'NAMEofYOURfield': FieldValue.delete()});
```

as mentioned [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#removing-data).

Comment: You're most welcome! Kindly consider accepting\marking it as an answer, thanks!